# In XCode clang 11 I get: No template named 'initializer_list' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, xcode

When someone on my team executes:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake .. -G Xcode
```

using XCode 10, and then opens the xcodeproj folder, Xcode starts and everything compiles.

In his project.pbxproj file are:

```
OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS = "-std=c++11 -pthread -fstrict-aliasing -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wextra -Wformat -Wpedantic -Wswitch-default -Wno-unknown-pragmas
OTHER_LDFLAGS = " -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  $HEAD/sdsp/metrics/test/build/sws-metrics/Release/libsws-metrics.a";
```

When I do the same thing using:

```
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
```

it does not compile.  I get errors:

- No template named 'initializer_list' in namespace 'std'
- A space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')

And my OTHER variables are blank.
I tried setting my OTHER variables to be like his- it didn't help.

In the project I tried all the various options for

```
Apple Clang - Language
  C Language Dialect - Compiler Default, c11, gnu11
Apple Clang - Language - C++
  C++ Language Dialect - C++11 [-std=c++11] (and gnu11 and the 14 and 17's)
  C++ Standard Library - Compiler Default, libstdc++, libc++
Apple Clang - Warnings - C++
  Using C++11 extensions in earlier versions of C++ - was No and I tried that and Yes
```

Nothing works.

We both create the makefiles from the same folder with:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake .. -G Xcode
```

Any idea what to do?

====
See a sample project on https://randy.strausses.net/info/be